# jQuery inside eval() is not working while running

Tags: javascript

I am using `eval` for converting the input text in the `h:inputTextarea` into JavaScript object. The input text is available in the `var` called `docSpec`. The inputting text is some arbitrary JavaScript object representation and the conversion in to object is working fine when i use the `eval` expression in the console. The expression which working in the console is like below

```
 eval(`(${docSpec})`)
```

But while running the application `eval` is not working. On inspecting i found that `eval` is missing the attribute like shown below. Why this missing happens. How to solve this

```
 eval(`()`)
```

[image]

The `docSpec` would contains the string like shown below

```
  {
onchange: function(){
console.log("I been changed now!")
}
}
```

I want this to be converted into java script object. For that purpose i am using `eval` and it is giving me the object when i do that on console but not on my original code.

Comment: `eval(\`()\`);` will fail

Comment: There is definitely a better way to achieve what you think this will achieve.  Please explain the bigger picture, *without using the word eval*.

Comment: What you're seeing is consistent with the behaviour when `docSpec` is an empty string and your code is generated on the serverside and ran on the client side. Of course this is only speculation on my end

Comment: You need to provide [mcve] demonstrating the issue. And please do not post images of code.

Comment: @apokryfos I have updated the question. The `docSpec` is not empty.

Comment: Also I don't see any jquery usage here. `${}` is not jquery inside [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Ok sorry for that. But how can i achieve that object from the `var`

Comment: @kemicofa  That  will fail. But i have given `  `eval(`(${docSpec})`)`   `  in my code. What i dont understand is why that is changing to empty

Comment: @Archer The only think i want to do is to convert the var string `docSpec` into JavaScript object

Comment: Are you sure `docSpec` is a string and not an object? `${docSpec}` will coerce the variable to a string and that might be an empty string if it provides a `toString` method that returns an empty string.

Comment: It would be a string because i am using `var docSpec = document.getElementById("jsobj:inputtextjs").value; ` in order to take my inputting arbitrary java script object representation. Also as i already said, i am getting the required object from the console

Comment: You've not understood my question and basically repeated yourself.  *Why* are you trying to convert a string to an object?  Your approach to solving whatever problem you're facing is wrong, so you need to take a step back from where you are and find a better way to achieve the end goal.  Forget about this very clear [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and try to focus on the real problem you're facing, not your potential solution.

Comment: @Archer I am trying to implement an XML editor in the repo [link]( https://github.com/michmech/xonomy.git) The editing suggestions on that XML structure work according to the  JavaScript object. So i want to store the object representation as string in db. But while i render `Xonomy` XML editor i need to pass that object not string, Then only suggestions will appear. For that purpose i want convert a string to an object. If you know some other ways to store the object in db, then please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by `eval('(' + docSpec + ')');`